# how to search data inside relations in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, associations, mongoid

Here I have search action in model

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
       self.or({date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i}})
    else
       scoped
    end
  end
```

It works fine now I want to add search for asset field also but I have relation

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :assets,:class_name => 'Asset'
```

"asset_ids" : [ ObjectId("5093a6996d7ab80e41000008") ]

I want to search for asset also.

```
 self.or({date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i},{asset.name: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i})
```

Now like this format I have to search asset name also. But this is wrong query. Any idea?
Since asset ids is here through asset id I want to search asset name . How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the mongoid_search gem by *mauriciozaffari*.  It should give you a more complete search option.  It should be able to search through relations.  I am also of the understanding it splits the search that is made by whitespace so you will have a more thorough search check it out [here](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

I haven't actually used this myself but as far as I can tell you will need to take the following steps:>/p?

1) install the gem in your gemfile
   `gem 'mongoid_search'` 
   (unless you are using mongoid 2.x.x in which case lock the gem at 0.2.8)

2) From the model that you want to search in add

```
    class Product
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Search
      field :brand
      field :name

      has_many   :tags
      belongs_to :category

      search_in :brand, :name, :tags => :name, :category => :name
    end

    class Tag
      include Mongoid::Document
      field :name

      belongs_to :product
    end

    class Category
      include Mongoid::Document
      field :name

      has_many :products
    end
```

So essentially what you are saying here as far as I can tell is; I have a model `Product` that has fields `brand` and `name`. `Product` can have many `Tags` and there can be many products attached to a `Category`.  Then you import `Mongoid::Search` in the product model, define what fields you want to search in so: `Product fields -> brand and name` also through the link `has many` search the `name` field in `Tags` and search the `name` field and in the `Category` model **I think!**.

Then from here you will be able to call:

`Product.full_text_search("value")`

Which will search your product model on `name` and `brand` also 
There are also a few options for full text search that you should look into from the README.md I put in the link above.  I think the most relevant one would be  `relevant_search` which I think allows you to search through the model associations

Again I haven't used this gem yet, but this is just what I gather from the README.md

Comment: after installing this gem. What should i do to my problem. Can u guide me working example to solve my problem by this gem. Working code